# PostgreSQL - Will it ever use two indices on the same table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Say you have a table with some indices:

```
create table mail
(
    identifier serial primary key,
    member text,
    read boolean
);

create index on mail(member_identifier);
create index on mail(read);
```

If you now query on multiple columns which have separate indices, will it ever use both indices?

```
select * from mail where member = 'Jess' and read = false;
```

That is, can PostgreSQL decide to first use the index on `member` to fetch all mails for Jess and then use the index on `read` to fetch all unread mails and then intersect both results to construct the output set?

I know you can have an index with multiple columns (on `(member, read)` in this case), but what happens if you have two separate indices? Will PostgreSQL pick just one or can it use both in some cases?

This is not a question about a specific query. It is a generic question to understand the internals.

Comment: Post a EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland This question is not about a specific query, but more a generic question to understand the internals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Postgres Documentation about multiple query indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html)

Article says it will create an abstract representation of where both indexes apply then combine the results.

> To combine multiple indexes, the system scans each needed index and
>   prepares a bitmap in memory giving the locations of table rows that
>   are reported as matching that index's conditions. The bitmaps are then
>   ANDed and ORed together as needed by the query. Finally, the actual
>   table rows are visited and returned.

Comment: Also see [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#multi-column-indexes).

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE fifteen
        (one serial PRIMARY KEY
        , three integer not NULL
        , five integer not NULL
        );

INSERT INTO fifteen(three,five)
SELECT gs%33+5,gs%55+11
FROM generate_series(1,60000) gs
        ;

CREATE INDEX ON fifteen(three);
CREATE INDEX ON fifteen(five);
ANALYZE fifteen;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT*
FROM fifteen
WHERE three= 7
AND five =13
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 60000
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
ANALYZE
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on fifteen  (cost=19.24..51.58 rows=31 width=12) (actual time=0.391..0.761 rows=364 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((five = 13) AND (three = 7))
   Heap Blocks: exact=324
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=19.24..19.24 rows=31 width=0) (actual time=0.355..0.355 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fifteen_five_idx  (cost=0.00..7.15 rows=1050 width=0) (actual time=0.136..0.136 rows=1091 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (five = 13)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fifteen_three_idx  (cost=0.00..11.93 rows=1788 width=0) (actual time=0.194..0.194 rows=1819 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (three = 7)
 Planning time: 0.259 ms
 Execution time: 0.796 ms
(10 rows)
```

---

Changing {33,55} to {3,5} will yield an index scan over only one index, plus an addtional filter condition .
(probablythe costsavings would be too little)